# Mysql returning more than one query error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay, below is the full php code for this

```
 $sql = "
 SELECT text 
      , creator
      , (SELECT name 
           FROM accounts 
          WHERE id IN (SELECT creator  
                         FROM groupcomments 
                        WHERE `group` = '$viewgroupid'
        ) AS account_name
      , (SELECT lastname 
           FROM accounts 
          WHERE id IN (SELECT creator 
                        FROM groupcomments 
                       WHERE `group` = '$viewgroupid'
                      )
        ) AS account_lastname
      , (SELECT role 
           FROM accounts 
          WHERE id IN (SELECT creator 
                         FROM groupcomments 
                        WHERE `group` = '$viewgroupid'
                      )
        ) AS account_role
      , (SELECT picture 
            FROM accounts 
           WHERE id IN (SELECT creator 
                          FROM groupcomments 
                         WHERE `group` = '$viewgroupid'
                       )
        ) AS account_picture
      , (SELECT id 
           FROM accounts 
          WHERE id IN (SELECT creator 
                         FROM groupcomments 
                        WHERE `group` = '$viewgroupid'
                      )
        ) AS account_id 
     FROM groupcomments 
    WHERE `group`='$viewgroupid'
 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $gc_text = $row['text'];
      $u_name = $row['account_name'];
      $u_lastname = $row['account_lastname'];
      $u_userid = $row['account_id'];
      $u_picture = $row['account_picture'];
      $u_role = $row['account_role'];
      include 'files/social/groupcomment.php';
    }
 //
}
```

Basically what this is supposed to do is to select data from the table `accounts` and from the table `groupcomments` then include a file which will echo the name and lastname, this works perfect when there's just one row in thetable `groupcomments` but as soon as i add another row i get the following error: `Subquery returns more than 1 row in htdocs/group.php:134 Stack trace: #0 htdocs/group.php(134): mysqli->query('SELECT text, cr...') #1 {main} thrown in htdocs/group.php on line 134`

and on line 134 is: `$result = $conn->query($sql);`

How can i get this to work with more than one row?

Comment: Ok now the query is readable

Comment: groupcomments  why not just use a join or a single sub query

Comment: because i also want to select from accounts, not just groupcomments

Comment: how can i use join for this

Comment: could you please edit my query and modify it

Comment: please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
    $sql = "
     SELECT gc.text 
          , gc.creator
          , a.name     AS account_name
          , a.lastname AS account_lastname
          , a.role     AS account_role
          , a.picture  AS account_picture
          , a.id       AS account_id 
         FROM groupcomments gc
         JOIN accounts a on gc.creator = a.id
        WHERE gc.`group`='$viewgroupid'
     ";
```

Your error indicates that there are more than groupcomments.creator having group = '$viewgroupid' and you got the error because you cannot put several names  within the same column in a row. With a join, this will not happen (you may get duplicate rows, but your particular query will not have that problem).

HTH,
Set

Answer (score 0):

You may redesign your sql code ,

```
$sql="SELECT 
text , creator, `ac`.name as account_name, `ac`.lastname as account_lastname, `ac`.role as account_role, `ac`.`id` as account_id 

FROM groupcomments AS gp 
INNER JOIN accounts as ac
ON `ac`.`id` =`gp`.`creator`

WHERE 
`gp`.`group`='$viewgroupid' 

"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $gc_text = $row['text'];
  $u_name = $row['account_name'];
  $u_lastname = $row['account_lastname'];
  $u_userid = $row['account_id'];
  $u_picture = $row['account_picture'];
  $u_role = $row['account_role'];
  include 'files/social/groupcomment.php';
}

}
```

Comment: Could you please re-design my whole sql query and if needed, change the results which are below the sql query, i'm quite lost now..

Comment: i get the following error: `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous in htdocs/group.php:142 Stack trace: #0 htdocs/group.php(142): mysqli->query('SELECT \ntext , ...') #1 {main} thrown in htdocs/group.php on line 142
`

Comment: and at line 142 is: `$result = $conn->query($sql);`

Comment: do you know how to fix it?

Comment: please change id as account_id  =>  `ac`.`id` as account_id.  and i did it in my answer.

Comment: downvoted for using legacy comma-separated join syntax. Please teach people how to use proper ANSI-compliant INNER JOINs instead. This code is a bit 20th-century. It works but it's not very clear and it's not the standards-compliant, recommended way to do it.